# How can I create a sub plot in Matplotlib with one of the subplots showing xaxis values on y-ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a subplot similar to the one shown below. I just sketched it up to give an idea of what kind of plot I am trying to build. Also, I created some dataset (see below) to reproduce my real dataframe. As you can see, it would have been much easier for me to build the subplots if there was no depth axis. The depth column is actually an xaxis, but I don't want to make a scatter plot (date vs depth) like other subplots, but instead I want to plot it in the same way as in the sample plot on the yaxis ticks. The date column should be shared among all subplots, so I can zoom in/out all the plots simultaneously. I am able to create simple subplots, but I couldn't get my head around how to add the depth column as shown here.

[image]

```
 date   depth   temp    pressure
01-01-22    1200    50  1200
02-01-22    1250    52  1250
03-01-22    1350    55  1300
04-01-22    1355    59  1220
05-01-22    1360    56  1200
06-01-22    1370    52  1230
```

additional info - I am using this code, and please see the plot below. It seems ok on the plot, but it is actually not doing what I needed. To show why it is not doing what I need, I plotted Datetime vs Depth (similar plot) on the next axis. As you can see, for instance, the depth 1000m should appear at a different Datetime value, whereas on Depth yticks 1000m appears at a later date. I think this Depth values on 1st axis yticks are evenly distributed. You can also see on the sketch, the depth values are not evenly distributed. I can't seem to figure out how to get it working the way I need it?

```
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10), sharey=True)
    
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3, width_ratios=[5,5,5])
    
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
    ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
    ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
    ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
    ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[2])
    
    ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5)
    
    ax1.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        
    ax1.set_ylim(df['DATE_TIME'].min(), df['DATE_TIME'].max())
    ax1.annotate('Datetime', xy=(0, 1.02), xycoords="axes fraction", fontsize=12, ha="center") 
fraction", fontsize="large", ha="center") 
    
    ax3 = ax1.twinx()
    spine_distance = 0.7
    ax3.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", spine_distance)) 
    ax3.tick_params(axis="y", direction="in", pad=-30)
    ax3.set_ylim(df['Depth (m)'].min(), df['Depth (m)'].max())
    ax3.annotate('Depth', xy=(spine_distance, 1.02), `xycoords="axes,fraction", fontsize="large", ha="center")`
    
    ax4.plot(df['Depth (m)'],df['DATE_TIME'], color='black', linewidth=0.9)
    ax4.annotate('Depth m', xy=(spine_distance, 1.02), xycoords="axes fraction", fontsize="large", ha="center")
    
    ax5.plot(df['temp'],df['DATE_TIME'], color='blue', linewidth=0.9)
    ax5.annotate('Temp', xy=(spine_distance, 1.02), xycoords="axes fraction", fontsize="large", ha="center")
    
    for ax in [ax4,ax5]:
        plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: But this is what my previous answer did, only that you asked previously not to plot anything. Create subplots with `sharey=True`, apply the answer to the first subplot, then plot `temp` and `pressure` against the shared y-axis. Not sure why you think this question is now fundamentally different. Nice sketch btw. How did you create this?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, sure I will definitely try your answer again, for some reason I couldn't get it working last time, I guess I messed up with the axis. If I can't get it working again, can I share my code for your review? That would be very helpful! The sketch is hand-drawn on https://excalidraw.com

Comment: @Mr.T I edited my question and added some more details. I would really appreciate if you could help me with this issue. Thanks)

Comment: After the sketch, I thought I understood what you want to plot but the current output (and those of your previous questions) puzzle me again. The sketch says `depth = f1(date)` with f1() being an invertible function, `pressure = f2(depth)`, and `temperature = f3(depth)`. Now your output shows that f1() is not an invertible function, e.g., the value 2000 appears at four different date times. So, how do you intend to plot linear scales of date and depth in parallel if the values cannot be converted into each other with a one-to-one mapping? I wouldn't know.

Comment: Yes, I understand this is puzzling. Let me explain the origin of the dataset to give you better understanding. When you drill a hole on oil rigs, you register time and drilling bit depth as your drilling bit penetrates and you record some properties (ex: rock resistivity, radiation emission etc). So you plot these rock properties against time and depth. Your rate of penetration is not constant, meaning you can drill 1m in an hour and sometimes 50m in an hour. Also, you can pick bit off the bottom and pull out of hole, and the bit depth is now decreasing whilst time is continuing to increase.

Comment: I added two picts on my question to show what I mean. The very last plot shows how the data is being recorded in real time during drilling. If the bit is picked off bottom and moved uphole, then depth would actually decrease. So, this is all recorded in real time and I have it in csv. And I would like to visualise this dataset as it is here. I understand we can't plot them on linear scale but I am thinking how to approach it. Perhaps I am taking a completely different approach, please advise if there is any other way to get around this visualisation.